# My Weather Indicator in Precise

Tags: 12.04, backport, my-weather-indicator

Does exist a backport of the 0.8.1 my-weather-indicator for Ubuntu 12.04. The latest version for Precise 12.04 seems to be 0.6.3 and it is not showing the forecast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The my-weather-indicator is possible to install on 12.04 from sources with

`git clone https://git.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator`

Install dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 python-tz python-cairo python-lxml python-dateutil python-requests python-requests-oauthlib geoclue-hostip geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils-extra
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-polib
sudo apt-get install python3-gi
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install python-dateutil
sudo pip3 install requests
sudo pip3 install requests-oauthlib
sudo pip3 install tz
sudo pip3 install dateutil
sudo pip3 install python-dateutil
sudo pip3 install python-tz
```

Edit following file:

```
gedit ~/my-weather-indicator/src/weatherwidget.py
```

Change the line 92 - 111 by removing the opacity parameter to:

```
#pin{
    border-image: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#pin:hover {
    transition: 1000ms linear;
    border-image: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Edit the myweatherindicator.py file with:

```
gedit ~/my-weather-indicator/src/myweatherindicator.py
```

change the line 388 from:

```
self.weather_updater = GLib.timeout_add_seconds(self.refresh * 3600,
                                                    self.update_weather)
```

to:

```
self.weather_updater = GLib.timeout_add_seconds(int(self.refresh * 3600),
                                                    self.update_weather)
```

Install with command:

```
sudo python ~/my-weather-indicator/setup.py install
```

You will need to edit the file and change the preferences manually in the file ~/.config/my-weather-indicator.conf.

Then run the my-weather-indicator with

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```